# discord.js shard.broadcastEval async

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm having an issue with implementing sharding into my bot

This returns correct:

```
await (async () => {
    return "test3";
}).call()
```

but once i shard it like this:

```
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
    await (async () => {
        return "test3";
    }).call()            
`)
```

it errors with `ReferenceError: await is not defined`

So this might not even be the correct way to do what i want.. What I'm trying to do is get all the guilds a user is an administrator of or has a certain role, I've already written the script, my issues is i can't get the response due to the await issue above.

Comment: Does the client have a suitable node version to parse `async/await`?

Comment: I'm running node 11.11.0

Comment: Don't mix callbacks and promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this :

```
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
    (async => { 
        return "test3";
    })();
`);
```

Check from here : [Discord.js Guide](https://discordjs.guide/sharding/additional-information.html#asynchronous-functions)

Comment: You have no idea the number of times I tried this example from Discord.js Guide just to have it fail with an error, turns out I was running an old version of discord.js and updated after I performed these tests already..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have use async/await in your case. you can just simply return promise from the function.

```
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
    (() => {
        return Promise.resolve("test3");
    }).call()            
`)
```

Hope it helps.